# Add a repository in AccountController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to add a `locationRepository` to the following code, but unsure how to do this? Normally I would have:

```
private ILocationRepository locationRepository;

public AccountController(ILocationRepository locationRepository)
        {
            this.locationRepository= locationRepository;
        }
```

How do I add the above code to the existing account controller listed below?

```
public AccountController()
            : this(null, null)
        {
        }

public AccountController(IFormsAuthentication formsAuth, IMembershipService service)
{
    FormsAuth = formsAuth ?? new FormsAuthenticationService();
    MembershipService = service ?? new AccountMembershipService();
} 

public IFormsAuthentication FormsAuth
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public IMembershipService MembershipService
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
```

Comment: Add it as another dependency on the constructor?

Comment: @CallumLinington It won't fail - it will initialize the defaults.

Comment: I commented out public AccountController(): this(null, null){ } and I get the error Can't create component - IFormsAuthentication which was not registered. - IMembershipService which was not registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516181/how-can-i-decouple-my-application-from-my-membership-service) I got the controller to work.

Controller

```
 private IMembershipService membershipService;
 private ILocationRepository locationRepository;


public AccountController(IMembershipService membershipService, 
                ILocationRepository locationRepository)
            {
                this.membershipService = membershipService;
                this.localRepository = locationRepository;
            }
```

Component Registrar

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IMembershipService)).ImplementedBy(typeof(AccountMembershipService)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass it as another constructor's argument:

```
public AccountController(
    IFormsAuthentication formsAuth,
    IMembershipService service,
    ILocationRepository locationRepository)
{
    FormsAuth = formsAuth ?? new FormsAuthenticationService();
    MembershipService = service ?? new AccountMembershipService();
    LocationRepository = locationRepository ?? new LocationRepository();
}

public IFormsAuthentication FormsAuth
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public IMembershipService MembershipService
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public ILocationRepository LocationRepository
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

Comment: thanks @BartoszKP I tried this and now I get the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Ros If you have another issue post it as another question, if it suits SO guidelines. In this case, please try debugging first.